# Creating workers in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a webserver with spring(mvc,data,security) which is serving tasks to physical devices(device count is around 100).
Device doesn't have query implementation inside. For example to execute some task u need write something like this:

```
Device driver = new DeviceDriver();
driver.setSettings(settingsJson);
driver.open(); // noone else can't connect to this device, open() can take up to 1 second
driver.setTask(taskJson);
driver.processTask(); // each task takes a few seconds to execute
String results = driver.getResults();
driver.close();
```

I'm not really an expert in designing architecture, so for now implemented webserver like this:

**TaskController**(@RestController) - processing incoming Post requests with tasks and persisting them to database.

**DeviceService**(@Service) - has init method, which gets list of devices from DB and creates/starts one worker per device. It passes taskRepository to each worker, so worker inside can save results of tasks.

**Worker** - extends **Thread**, it gets next task from database with certain period(via loop with sleep). When task executed worker saves result to db and updates status of task.

Does this approach makes any sense? Maybe there is better way to do this using spring components instead of Thread.

Comment: In your case , you are passing taskRepository reference to each device which is thread type, so you might end up with writing some extra process to maintain repo  and ensuring the persistence. What if you are updating some records with each device. Either you should synchronize the critical process or get the work done back from workers and persist them in service itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would not create workers for each device (client). Because your controller will be able to serve concurrent requests being deployed on a thread-per-request based server. Additionally, this is not scalable at all- what if there is a new device on-boarded? You need to make changes on the database, restart the service with the current design!!

If you need device specific actions, you can just pass that on the request parameters from the device client. Therefore, there is no need to keep a predefined set of workers.

So, the design looks good except the worker set.

Comment: Adding new device is not a problem, I can simply create new thread for new device in WorkersService it has concurrentHashmap<Id, worker> inside.

Comment: I would not design it that way given it doesn't bring great advantage to the table

Answer (score 0):

Use the @Scheduled annotation on your functions to build something like cron